# ¿Qué metodo me devuelve la clave dando como argumento su valor en los diccionarios?

Tags: python, diccionarios

¿Qué metodo me devuelve la clave dando como argumento su valor en los diccionarios?

Por ejemplo tengo este diccionario:

```
relacion = {1: 35, 2: 10, 3: 50, 4: 40, 5: 5, 6: 20, 7: 7, 8: 15, 9: 10, 10: 35}
```

y quiero buscar la clave del valor `35` que en este caso sería `1`

Comment: Que yo sepa esta funcion no existe en python, llevo aproximadamente 3 años trabajando con el y en ningun momento la eh visto.

Comment: Pero una posible solucion seria que crearas una función. que lo haga, pero tomando en cuanta que el valor se puede repetir y que tendrias que devolver todas las claves conicidentes.

Comment: Te puedo dejar en las respuestas una función muy sencillas que te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 4):

Puede crear una función que filtre los datos y devuelva una lista con todas
las claves que coincidan con el valor. Aquí te dejo una función que te puede ayudar:

```
def get_keys(obj: dict, value) -> list:
    # obj representa el dict de donde buscarás las claves
    # value sera el valor que usarás para obtener las coincidencias

    # Para esta función usaré list comprehensions

    # 1) Iteramos sobre obj usando ítems para que me devuelva una tupla con el formato (key, value)
    # 2) Filtramos solo los valores que coinciden con el que pasamos a la función
    # 3) Devolvemos la clave

    return [
        k # 3)
        for k, v in obj.items() # 1)
        if v == value # 2)
    ]
```

El nombre de la función lo puedes cambiar por el que te parezca más conveniente.

Esta es una forma que a mi parecer es bastante sencilla y se adapata a los estándares de python. Espero que haya sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma alternativa a los iteradores, que puede ser marginalmente mas performante, siempre que los diccionarios no sean demasiado extensos, y si solo te interese obtener el primer resultado, es usar el método `index()` de las listas para ubicar el índice del valor buscado y usarlo luego para obtener la clave:

```
valor = 31
clave = list(relacion.keys())[list(relacion.values()).index(valor)]
print(clave)
```

Básicamente transformamos `relacion.values()` en una lista para poder usar `index()`, replicamos lo mismo pero para `relacion.keys()` y usamos este índice para ubicar la clave. El orden de ambas listas es el mismo, [según la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), estaría garantizado.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149770/6836377